# Failed to import python module from different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code structure in python3:

```
- datalake
  __init__.py
  utils
     __init__.py
     utils.py
  lambdas
     __init__.py
     my-lambdas.py
- tests
    __init__.py
    demo.py
```

All `init__.py` files are empty.

My problem is how I can import `datalake` module from `tests/demo.py`? 
I tried `from datalake.utils import utils` in `demo.py` but when I run `python tests/demo.py` from command line, I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datalake'`.

If I use this code:

```
from ..datalake.utils import utils
```

I will get error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

I also tried to import the module `utils` from `my-lambda.py` file which also failed. The code in `my-lambda.py` is `from datalake.utils import utils` but I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datalake'` error when run `python datalake/lambda/my-lambda.py` from command line.

How can I import the module?

Comment: Is the parent directory (the one containing both datalake and tests) on your PYTHONPATH? I think if it is, it should find the module.

Comment: It is not. Do I have to add the path on `PYTHONPATH` as environment variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a command like `python tests/demo.py`, the folder you are in does not get added to the PYTHONPATH, the script folder does. So a top-level import like `import datalake` will fail. To get around this you can run your tests as a module:

Python 2:

```sh
python -m tests/demo
```

Python 3:

```sh
python -m tests.demo
```

and any `datalake` imports in `demo.py` will work.

It sounds like what you really want to do is have a folder with tests separate to your main application and run them. For this I recommend [py.test](http://doc.pytest.org), for your case you can read [Tests Outside Application Code](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code) for how to do it. TL;DR is run your tests from your top level project folder with `python -m py.test` and it will work.

Comment: I got this error `No module named tests/demo'` when run `python -m tests/demo. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: @ZhaoYi are you in the top project folder? so that `tests/demo.py` exists from the folder you are currently in?

Comment: Yes the file `tests/demo.py` exists in the current directory which is the root of project

Comment: @ZhaoYi sorry it seems this syntax only works in python 2. use `python -m tests.demo` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `my-lambdas.py` is not importable with the `import` statement as hyphens are not valid in Python identifiers. Try to follow [PEP-8's naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), such as `mylambdas.py`.

Otherwise the package structure looks good, and it should be importable as long as you are at the level *above* `datalake/`, e.g., if you were in the directory `myproject/` below:

```
myproject
├── datalake
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utils
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   └── lambdas
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── mylambdas.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── demo.py
```

Then this should work:

```
~/myproject$ python -c 'from datalake import utils'
```

Otherwise, setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH to the path above `datalake/` or modifying `sys.path` are both ways of changing where Python can import from. See the official [tutorial on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) for more information.

Also some general advice: I've found it useful to stick with simple modules rather than packages (directories) until there is a need to expand. Then you can change `foo.py` into a `foo/` directory with an `__init__.py` file and `import foo` will work as before, although you may need to add some imports to the `__init__.py` to maintain API compatibility. This would leave you with a simpler structure:

```
myproject
├── datalake
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── lambdas.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── demo.py
```

Comment: How do I run the `tests/demo.py` from command line? If I am currently in `myproject` directory, run `python -m tests/demo` gives me `No module named tests/demo` error.

Comment: If these are unit tests, the unit testing framework often has a runner that discovers these. For example with [pytest](http://pytest.org/) (which is great, btw), you just run `pytest` from `myproject/` and it will discover appropriately named files (but they should be named something like `test_lambdas.py`). If `demo.py` is something you want to interactively run, try `python -m tests.demo`. Note the dot (`.`) instead of slash (`/`) in the module path.

Comment: They are not unit tests. they are demo code to run our project from command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the module directory into your `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("your/own/modules/folder")  # like sys.path.append("../tests")
```

but this is a one-shot method, which is just valid at this time, the added path is not permanent, it will be eliminated after the code completed execution.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to import the file directly instead of using from, like `import util`

Answer (score -1):

you can try run :

```py
python -m datalake.lambda.my-lambda
```

follow: https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m